# How to make Amazon CPM ads load asychronously?

Tags: javascript, ads, amazon-advertising-api

I have an Amazon CPM ad code which looks like this:

```
<script type="text/javascript" language="javascript" src="//c.amazon-adsystem.com/aax2/getads.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" language="javascript">
  //<![CDATA[
    aax_getad_mpb({
      "slot_uuid":"24386343-232a-4s3d-54s7-f5d4g53b95s7"
    });
  //]]>
</script>
```

The ad displays at the top of my webpage and is render blocking.  Very noticeable impact on site experience.  How can I make it load asynchronously?

Comment: Did you manage to load it async?

Comment: Unfortunately, I did not.